# Customize reset password form redirect problem

Tags: forms, password, reset

I would like to create my own reset password form and page, I mean this page:
[image]
I have already created a page template for the reset password form, the code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Page - Reset Password
 */
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( site_url( 'login' ) );
}
get_header();
?>

<div id="content" class="content-area" role="main">
    <div class="forms-wrapper">
        <div class="form-reset-password-wrapper">
            <h1>Reset your password</h1>
            <form id="form-reset-password" name="resetpassform" class="form-reset-password" action="<?php echo site_url( '/wp-login.php?action=resetpass', 'https' ); ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="hidden" id="user_login" value="<?php echo $_GET['login']; ?>" autocomplete="off">
                <p class="form-row">
                    <label for="user_pass">New password
                    <input type="password" name="user_pass" id="user_pass">
                </p>
                <p class="form-row">
                    <label for="user_pass_confirm">Confirm new password
                    <input type="password" name="user_pass_confirm" id="user_pass_confirm">
                </p>
                <p class="reset-password-submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="reset-password-btn" class="reset-password-btn" value="Submit"/>
                </p>
                <div class="form-reset-password-errors"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is how it looks:
[image]

On form submit I fire a function using Ajax to validate these passwords and change them if everything goes well, so far so good.

**How do people get to see this page?** basically there is the *request a password reset using email address form* that looks like this:
[image]

After the email is received the user can click on a link that looks similar to this:

```
https://example.com/wp-login.php?action=rp&key=tkFUnvcJmhu30nRxqjpt&login=example%gmail.com
```

Now, in functions PHP I used this function to redirect users to my custom page with the `$_GET` variables but it's not working, I need your help please! here is the code:

```
/*
 * Redirect to custom reset password page
 */
function override_reset_password_form_redirect() {
    $action = isset( $_GET['action'] ) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
    $key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? $_GET['key'] : '';
    $login = isset( $_GET['login'] ) ? $_GET['login'] : '';

    if ( 'wp-login.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow'] && ( 'rp' == $action  || 'resetpass' == $action ) ) {
        wp_redirect( site_url( '/reset-password/' ) . '?key=' . $key . '&login=' . $login );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'override_reset_password_form_redirect' );
```

Comment: Is init called on the password reset form? That seems like a security risk to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to your `functions.php` to achieve what you are after. The action `init` doesn't seem to fire in time for what you are looking for.

```
if($_GET['action']==='rp' && strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'wp-login.php')) {
    $key = isset( $_GET['key'] ) ? $_GET['key'] : '';
    $login = isset( $_GET['login'] ) ? $_GET['login'] : '';
    wp_redirect( site_url( '/reset-password/' ) . '?key=' . $key . '&login=' . $login );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: That's also what I thought, I was thinking there might be a different hook for that maybe. Thanks Liam, i'll try.

Comment: Let me know if this works for you. @odedta

Comment: Sure, it's the weekend here :-)